# How to send an email to the address stored in an EditText?

Tags: android, email, send

Lets say I have a button and an edit text in a layout. How do i send an email that says some messages to that address which is the edit text in android studio ?

Comment: first get the email from edittext to a string, and then search how to `send email from android` in google.

Comment: Yeah i searched the answers regarding my query. In my case i just want to send confirmation email to the address in edit text.

Answer (score 2):

```
 String email = editText.getText().toString();
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, 
 Uri.parse("mailto:" + email));
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Enter subject here");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enter email body here");
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, 
 "Choose email client")));
```

Answer (score 0):

First Get text from your email edittext. Then use this email to whom you are sending email.

```
String email = emailfield.getText().toString()
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , email);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try {
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "No email clients installed.",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: createChooser creates a client chooser dialog box right? is there any way to specify email address directly that is to be sent from without creating the choose dialog box?

Comment: This might help you. 
http://www.edumobile.org/android/send-email-on-button-click-without-email-chooser/